# How to find out corresponding repository for the given entity class in spring boot

Tags: repository

I want to export all records into csv file for the given table. So need to Fetch corresponding repository for the given entity class. So give me solution.

Comment: what solution is about: fetch records into csv or just how to fetch? in spring boot, if you use repository, there is already findAll function there to use. just need to declare model

Comment: For example I have 10 entity class. Each entity represent each table in DB. So I give one table name, corresponding records needs to be exported to csv file. My exact question is I have to find out exact entity class and repository for the given table.

Comment: in your application, there is the way to specific which entity to export. you can use that as key and select corresponded repository and column names. the function to export can be generic and have the repository + columns name as dependencies